# Poking the Android PowerManager (like if the user had just interacted with it)

Tags: android, wakelock, power-management, android-wake-lock, android-powermanager

I have an external device connected to an android tablet. I would like that interactions with this external device have the same effect on power management that if the user interacted directly with the tablet.

In other words, I'm looking for a way to reset the sleep countdown without holding a full wakelock on the device.

I've found a way, but it's a bit twisty and there ought to be something more official: I take a wakelock and release it right away!

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakelock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
                               PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                               PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE), TAG);
wakelock.acquire();
wakelock.release();
```

Any better way to do this?